# Customizing Layout Zest Draw2d

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, draw2d, zest

I'm using Zest's tree layout to display a graph. However at present, the lines connecting the nodes are like this.

```
  A
   / \
  B   C
 /\   /\
D  E F  G
```

How do I instead make it appear like this?

```
  A
  __I__
  B    C
 _|_  _I_
D   E F  G
```

Comment: Apparently this is planned for version 2.0. [Here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=284972) is a bug report.

Comment: @Baz Thanks. That makes things difficult. Do you know of any other framework like zest where such connections would be possible?

Comment: Well, apparently Draw2d itself it able to do it, but then you'll loose the layout. I suppose GEF can do it (not entirely sure), but that's a huge framework, that I have never worked with.